# Unit testing GatewayFilter causes NullPointerException

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-webflux

I'm trying to unit test my `GatewayFilter`, however I'm having troubles running even simple test.

This is small example of what is failing right now

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SomeFilterTest {

    private final GatewayFilter gatewayFilter = (exchange, chain) ->
            Mono.just("Hello")
                    .flatMap(this::doSomething)
                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> chain.filter(exchange)));

    private Mono<Void> doSomething(String value) {
        System.out.println(value);
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    @Test
    void test1() {
        var exchange = MockServerWebExchange.from(MockServerHttpRequest.get("/").build());
        var chain = mock(GatewayFilterChain.class);

        gatewayFilter.filter(exchange, chain).block();
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly, it is failing because of

> The Mono returned by the supplier is null
> java.lang.NullPointerException: The Mono returned by the supplier is
> null  at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:246)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)    at
> reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4361)

And to be honest, I have no idea why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

You have not stubbed out the `filter` method call on your mock object, `GatewayFilterChain`. As a result, the supplier `() -> chain.filter(exchange)` returns `null`. You are not allowed to create a `Mono` with a value of `null`, hence the exception.

As a result your test should look something like

```java
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        var exchange = MockServerWebExchange.from(MockServerHttpRequest.get("/").build());
        var chain = mock(WebFilterChain.class);

        // stubbing behaviour on our mock object
        given(chain.filter(exchange)).willReturn(Mono.empty());

        gatewayFilter.filter(exchange, chain).block();
    }
```

Additionally, I would suggest using `StepVerifier` instead of using `block()` in unit tests. This is provided by `reactor-test` and is purpose built for unit testing reactive code

```java
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        var exchange = MockServerWebExchange.from(MockServerHttpRequest.get("/").build());
        var chain = mock(WebFilterChain.class);

        given(chain.filter(exchange)).willReturn(Mono.empty());

        StepVerifier.create(gatewayFilter.filter(exchange, chain))
                .verifyComplete();
    }
```

Here is a very useful [Step Verifier Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/reactive-streams-step-verifier-test-publisher) to help you get started